# JNA direct call not working with argument Structure[]

Tags: java, native, jna

I have a C++ function:

```
struct Result {
    //...
};
bool doSomething(Result[]);
```

If I use the following JNA binding, the function call works fine:

```
public class Result extends Structure {
    //...
}

public interface CPPLibrary extends Library {
    public static final CPPLibrary INSTANCE = (CPPLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("dllname");
    boolean doSomething(Result[]);
}
```

But with **direct call**, I hit an *IllegalArgumentException* saying **class [Lcom.usta.Result; is not a supported argument type (in method calcPV01 in class com.usta.CPPLibrary)**. My JNA code for the direct call-mapping:

```
public class CPPLibrary implements Library {
    Native.register("dllname");
    public static native boolean doSomething(Result[]);
}
```

I can see in **com.sun.jna.Function#convertArgument()** explicitly handles *Structure[]* but **com.sun.jna.Native#getConversion()**, which is used by direct call-mapping, does not handle *Structure[]*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion is trivial, just call Structure.getPointer() on the first element of your structure array (assuming that you got the array from Structure.toArray in the first place).

You're actually better off with that when using direct mapping; when passing non-primitive, non-pointer types the JNI layer has to call back into the VM to derive the appropriate native data.

Feel free to file an issue for support of Structure[] arguments in direct mappings.   That should be supported (JNA documentation notes that arrays of Pointer/String/WString/NativeMapped are *not* supported).

Answer (score 0):

If I use a different method signature:

```
boolean doSomething(Pointer results);
```

it does work. But then I have to convert from Result[] to a Pointer my self.